Ubuntu Studio 24.04 - many XRUNS generated while mouse-hovering on the KDE taskbar - SOLVED (WORKAROUND)
I recently upgraded from Ubuntu Studio 23.10 to 24.04.
In 23.10 I was using the Jack stack while now in 24.04, due to that config being deprecated, I moved to the Pipewire stack.
In general I can say PW works pretty well OOTB. I can set a buffer size of 128/48000 on my M Audio Fast Track Ultra 8 and performance is as good as it was with Jack.
But I have noticed a strange problem/fenomenon which I did not notice in 23.10.
I get loads of XRUNS when I hover the mouse cursor over the KDE taskbar (I mean the widget in the panel where you have favorite/running app icons).
In example, say that I run Ardour with a mid-size session (10 to 12 recorder tracks with plugins and stuff).
If I just use Ardour everything is fine, no XRUN at all despite the buffer setting (128 48000).
However, as soon as I hover the icons in the taskbar (doesn't matter if Ardour is playing or not) the XRUN count immediatelly bumps by 20/30 and the audio cracks a lot. Even Ardour displays high DSP load while moving the mouse over the icons.
So I am wondering could this be a bug with KDE? Is anybody else able to reproduce this problem?
I can eventually share a video of this happening.
Maybe this is an issue in my installation due to the upgrade from 23.10 and I should probably attempt a fresh install first, yet I'd like to ask if this is something reproducible by others.

The issue appears to be related to the graphic stack and I have found a workaround for it. The computer has an old NVIDIA GTS 450. That old card does not have NVIDIA drivers available in Ubuntu (should be supported by legacy 3xx drivers) so I use the default driver (I guess nouveau). This situation in combination with WAYLAND leads to the issue. I found out that simply using xorg eliminates  the xrun issue. I am not sure what other issues could be generated by the use of xrog vs wayland. Anyway, just thought to point that out as this may apply to others.
